# java operator mod result wrong issue

Tags: java

I am a java beginer.
I am trying to operate 1 byte, but the value of %mod operation is strange.
Here is the code:

```
ArrayList<byte[]> bytelist;
MessageDigest.GetInstance("MD5")
String MD5 = new BigInteger(1,byteBuffer).toString(16);
byte[] buffer = new byte[2];
System.arraycopy (byteBuffer,0, buffer, 0, 2);
byte.add(buffer);


byte bOperand = 16;  // (0x10)
aOperand = (byte)(bytelist.get(0)[0] % bOperand); // == 213 == (0xD5)
System.out.println("after : " + String.format("%02x",aOperand));
```

result : f5 ( dec -11) 
expect : 5

Comment: Please check ma code again. Get MD5 String and copied the first 2 bytes. One byte of that was mod-operated.

Comment: Also note: what exactly is the point of mixing Lists and array. At least, when you think you have a problem with the mod operator, why dont you give us a [mcve] that just does that: use the mod operator? Dont confuse yourself (and your readers) with things that DO NOT contribute to your problem. Always digest your problem, and gets to its inner core.

Answer (score 2):

Java's bytes are always signed, so they have the range of -128 to 127. The unsigned byte 213 is represented as -43 in Java (both have binary representation 11010101).

-43 mod 16 is -11, which is why you got the unexpected result.

To operate on the unsigned byte, you need a larger data type, like an `int`. You can use `Byte.toUnsignedInt` to convert a signed byte to a positive `int`, and then operate on that:

```
aOperand = (byte)(Byte.toUnsignedInt(aOperand) % 16);
```

Comment: @worldstar If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Answer (score 0):

`byte`s, like all numeric types in Java, are signed. So there is no byte representing 213 — it overflows to -43.

Comment: Is there a way to calculate only 1 byte as an unsigned type? I'm a c++ developer, so I'll show you a simple example.. unsigned char buff =  0x21; buff % 0x10; // == 0x01 I need this.

Comment: See Sweeper's answer: `Byte.toUnsignedInt()`

Comment: @worldstar There are very few operations in Java that operate on single bytes. Most operators operate on `int`, `long`, `float` and `double`. Note that even though `%=` _seems_ to operate on single bytes, binary numeric promotion to `int` still takes place on `%`, and the result is implicitly casted back to `byte`.